# Multivariable taylor polynomial of a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I asked a similar question yesterday but I realized it was worded very poorly so I deleted it and I am going to try and rephrase my question. I want to find the taylor approximation ([taylor polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables)) at the point $(1,0,0)$ of the following transformation:

$$f(r, \phi,\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}br \sin{\phi}\cos{\theta}\\ar\sin{\phi} \sin{\theta}\\cr \cos{\phi}\end{pmatrix}$$

where $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$.

Since the taylor approximation that I linked and want to use can only be used for scalar valued functions, I have to approximate every component seperately. The formula for the expansion is:

$$T_{2,f}=f(\vec{x}_0)+\nabla^Tf(\vec{x}_0)(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0)+\frac{1}{2}(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0)^TH_f(\vec{x}_0)(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0)$$

where $H_f$ is the Hessian matrix and $\vec{x}_0=(1,0,0)^T$. Now I am facing the following problem:

> 1. What does $\vec{x}$ in this formula refer to?

Up until this point I had only used this formula with cartesian coordinates where $\vec{x}=(x,y,z)^T$ but in this case I am not sure what this is referring to. Do I use $\vec{x}=(r,\phi,\theta)$ or do I use the spherical basis coordinates?

> 2. In case I have to use spherical coordinates for my $\vec{x}$, vector, do I also have to somehow transform my $\vec{x}_0$ vector or is this vector already in spherical coordinates?

**EDIT 1:** based on the suggestion from Duca_Conte I tried to do it by converting to cartesian coordinates $f(r,\phi, \theta)=f(x,y,z)=(bx,ay,cz)^T$ but the problem becomes "too easy" (almost trivial) and the answer doesn't make much sense so I am not sure that change of coordinates works. If anyone as any idea how to do this I would be very grateful.

**EDIT 2:** This is the solution I have so far.

1. Write the transformation in cartesian coordinates:

$$f(r,\phi, \theta)=f(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}bx \\ay \\cz\end{pmatrix}$$

2. Calculate the second-order taylor approximation for each component:

$$T_{2,f_1}=b+b(\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z})\begin{pmatrix}x-1\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}+0=2b$$

$$T_{2,f_2}=0 \\ T_{2,f_1}=0$$

$$\implies T_{2,f}= \begin{pmatrix}2b \\ 0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

This doesn't look right and I am wondering if I am making a big mistake somewhere.

> Can anyone tell me if this is the correct way to do this and if not, suggest a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is mainly a problem of notation; e.g., the names of the variables in your source about the Taylor expansion conflict with the names of the variables in your concrete problem.

You are given a vector-valued map
$${\bf f}:\quad {\mathbb R}^3\to{\mathbb R}^3,\qquad(r,\phi,\theta)\mapsto (x,y,z)\ .$$
This map is of a certain practical use, and has a geometric interpretation in terms of affinely scaled spherical coordinates. But this should not disturb us from mechanically applying the rules for finding the Taylor coefficients of ${\bf f}$. In a figure you maybe won't draw the $(r,\phi,\theta)$-space ${\mathbb R}^3$ on the left; but it is there, and has three ordinary axes. You will only draw the $(x,y,z)$-space, and if $a=b=c=1$ you will show the geometric meaning of $r$, $\phi$, $\theta$.

Now
$${\bf f}(r,\phi,\theta)=\bigl(x(r,\phi,\theta),y(r,\phi,\theta),z(r,\phi,\theta)\bigr)\ .$$
You have decided to treat the three functions $x(\cdot)$, $y(\cdot)$, $z(\cdot)$ separately. This seems reasonable. Let's consider the function$$x(\cdot):\quad(r,\phi,\theta)\mapsto x(r,\phi,\theta)=b\,r\,\sin\phi\,\cos\theta\ .$$
At this point we need your formula for the Taylor expansion. In terms of the variables at stake it comes as follows: Write $(r,\phi,\theta)=:{\bf r}$ and $(1,0,0)=:{\bf r}_0$.$\ {}^*)\ $ Then
$$T_{2,{\bf r}_0} x({\bf r})=x({\bf r}_0)+\nabla x({\bf r}_0)\cdot({\bf r}-{\bf r}_0)+{1\over2}({\bf r}-{\bf r}_0)H_x({\bf r}_0)({\bf r}-{\bf r}_0)\ .\tag{1}$$
Here $T_{2,{\bf r}_0} x$ means "second order Taylor polynomial of the function $x(\cdot)$, centered at ${\bf r}_0$", and I have omitted the ${}^T$ symbols. Now we have to evaluate the things appearing on the RHS of $(1)$:
$$\eqalign{x({\bf r}_0)&=x(1,0,0)=0,\cr
{\bf r}-{\bf r}_0&=(r-1,\phi,\theta),\cr
\nabla x(r,\phi,\theta)&=\bigl(b\sin\phi\cos\theta,b\,r\cos\phi\cos\theta,-b\,r\sin\phi\sin\theta\bigr),\cr
\nabla x({\bf r}_0)&=(0,b\,r,0)\ .\cr}$$
I leave it to you to compute the Hessian  $H_x({\bf r}_0)$. This will in the end be a $3\times3$-matrix of real numbers.

${}^*)\ $ If $(1,0,0)$ means the point with $(x,y,z)$-coordinates $(1,0,0)$ then ${\bf r}_0=(r_0,\phi_0,\theta_0)$ has to be determined numerically from the  equations.

Comment: Thank you for this great response. A lot of my questions were answered, however there are still a few things that I don't understand yet. 1) As far as I understand $r,\phi, \theta$ are spherical coordinates. Why then, don't I have to use the gradient and hessian for spherical coordinates? 2) Is the vector $\vec{x}$ in the taylor polynomial always "just" the column vector of the variables in my problem? (In this case $\begin{pmatrix}r \\ \phi \\ \theta \end{pmatrix}$)

Comment: @qmd: See my edit. 1) The variables $(r,\phi,\theta)$ are new variables, like $(u, v, w)$, used to create a parametric representation of the $(x,y,z)$-space ${\mathbb R}^3$. This representation is called ${\bf f}$, and we are told to compute the Taylor expansion of this ${\bf f}$. 2) Yes.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you very much for taking the time to write such a thorough response.

Answer (score 1):

First choose in which coordinates you want to work. Looking at your function $f$, I suppose that the best choice is the spherical.

Of corse you can write your vector $\mathbf{x}$ in polar coordinates, but you have to be careful, since also the gradient and the Hessian must be in the same coordinate system. As long you are coherent with your choice it should work. And yes, also $\mathbf{x}_0$ must be written in spherical coordinates, if not you are subtracting lengths to angles, and it does not make sense.

Here you can find all the transformations you need: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just to clarify, I am trying to approximate at the the point $(1,0,0)$. Is this already in terms of $(r, \phi, \theta)$ or is this in $(x,y,z)$? In other words, in my approximation for the first component, would $f(\vec{x}_0)=b\cdot 1 \cdot \sin{0} \cdot \cos{0}=0$?

Comment: This is up to you to decide. In spherical coordinates $(1,0,0)$ means the North Pole, which in cartesian is $(0,0,1)$. Otherwise, $(1,0,0)$ in cartesian means the point with $x=1$, which in polar is $(1,0,\pi/2)$ (or something like this, it depends how you choose your angles).

Comment: But isn't the question worded poorly then? Because approximating at (1,0,0) given in cartesian is not the same as (1,0,0) in spherical right? So depending on whether I chose this point to be in spherical or cartesian, my approximation will be different or am I missing something here?

Comment: That's the point. A triple $(a,b,c)$ without a coordinate system do not represent anything in the space. Since everything is given in spherical coordinates I suppose that $(1,0,0)$ is actually the North Pole. But that's simply a guess. Nevertheless, since you can compute the Taylor expansion for any point, just give the expression for a generic $(r,\varphi,\theta)$, and then compute the two cases, one of the two must be right.

Comment: I can't really find what the Hesse matrix is in spherical coordinates and I am pretty sure we havent done that in class before so I am thinking I want to do this in cartesian coordinates but then I would have to make a change of variables for the transformation itself right?

Comment: Exactly, this is easy having explicit change of variables: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Comment: look where is written $x=$, $y=$, $z=$ in terms of $r,\varphi,\theta$

Comment: I think I got it. Basically it's really easy to change the coordinates if I am not mistaken. I can just write: $$f(r,\phi,\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}br \sin{\phi}\cos{\theta}\\ar\sin{\phi} \sin{\theta}\\cr \cos{\phi}\end{pmatrix} \iff f(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}bx\\ay\\cz\end{pmatrix}$$
or have I confused myself again?

Comment: no, that's correct.

Comment: Perfect. I will try to calculate it now by assuming $\vec{x}_0=(1,0,0)$ in cartesian coordinates. I will attach it to my opening post. I would be really grateful if you could take a quick look at it once I am done. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: I am sorry if I am not getting this but I am not sure writing it in cartesian coordinates works. If the change of variables is correct then the Hessian matrix is always zero since all second partial derivatives of the components are zero. Therefore I am left with:

$$T_{2,f}=f(\vec{x}_0)+\nabla^T f(\vec{x}_0)(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0)$$

For every component. Since the point I am approximating at is $(1,0,0)$ the taylor approximation of the second and third component als also zero so it almost trivially becomes: $$T_{2,f}=\begin{pmatrix} 2b\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$. This doesn't look right.

Comment: Are you sure that $\theta$ and $\varphi$ given in the Wikipedia article are defined in the same way you did in the problem? There are several way to do that. If yes, then it is correct since the transformation is linear, the hessian must be zero.

Comment: Now you have to translate all in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Also, $(1,0,0)$ in spherical becomes in cartesian $(0,0,1)$ (with the interpretation of the North Pole we were talking about before).